# Background not visible in surface view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a view which extends surface view when i am trying to add the custom view to frame layout , frame layout back ground is not visible.. please provide me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to render the background by yourself within the surface view. As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) says:

> the SurfaceView punches a hole in its window to allow its surface to be displayed.

So nothing that is placed behind a surface view would be rendered.