# Android: When I stack two SurfaceView's, the higher one completely blacks out the screen

Tags: android, draw, surfaceview, android-relativelayout

I'll start with my code:

```
    backgroundView = new SurfaceView(this);
    mainLayout.addView(backgroundView);

    timerView = new SurfaceView(this);
    timerView .setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);

    mainLayout.addView(timerView );
```

This is how I'm setting up my SurfaceViews. BackgroundView is a background, and timerview is simply numbers drawn onto the background. For some reason, when both draw, the timer is on top(which is good), but it blacks out the rest of the view so I can't see the background anymore. I've tried making it transparent, but that doesn't seem to work. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243958/background-not-visible-in-surface-view

Comment: I don't really understand that answer. What does it mean by "punches a hole in the window"? Can surface view be customized to not do that?

Comment: Better answer is found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391089/how-to-make-surfaceview-transparent